# Given an instance of Calendar, what is the simplest way to determine if it is one hour old?

Tags: java, date, time, comparison

Chasing some subtle, annoying bugs in a block of code.

This code is given an instance of Calendar which was created at the start of some event. We need to figure out if this event is an hour old.

I know of several ways to do this:

- using JodaTime and calculating a Duration
- comparing the given Calendar to a new Calendar created for one hour ago
- comparing the given Calendar.getTime to a Date created for one hour ago

Each of these methods has its own quirks and seems to have code smells. Is there a simple, concise way to express "happened between now and one hour ago" in Java?

When I unit test this I would check:

- 45 minutes ago (true)
- 61 minutes ago (false)
- 0 minutes ago (true)
- -1 minutes ago (error or true?)

Comment: You could create a Calendar given the current time, roll it back by one hour and then use Calendar's `compareTo` method - did not try it but may work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new Calendar instance (with current date/time) and compare it with the given one:

```
public boolean isWithinHour(Calendar given)
{
    long oldTime = given.getTimeInMillis();
    long newTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

    long diff = newTime - oldTime;
    return (diff <= 3600 * 1000);    // 3600 seconds in millis
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a personal preference I'd choose Joda-Time, but I think the implementation is not important. What is important is being clear on the purpose and create a method that you can use.

First you'd better **define what means** `happened one hour ago`.

- Does it mean exactly a hour ago?
- Does it mean within a hour ago?
- Does it mean between 45 minutes ago and 1 hour and 15 minutes ago?

After that you choose one of the methods that you mentioned. and you write your own **method with a descriptive name** that should read naturally in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not very different from the methods you listed, but I don't see how or why it smells:

```
if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() + (60L * 60L * 1000L)) <= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    // created more than one hour ago
}
```

Comment: The "code smell" is very faint. It comes from a general unease with the various Calendar, Date, Time, and Joda Time classes that could be used plus the more general concerns about time zones, leap years, etc.  To remove that faint aroma of code smell, a simple unambiguous statement is best. I think this getMillis approach is close to that.

Answer (score 0):

The method I would use is to compare against a timestamp 1 hour in the past:

```
return cal.getTimeInMillis() < (System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000L * 60L * 60L);
```